# Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/book/create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Iam trying to insert some data in to database.but showing following error

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/book/create"
```

code for form submittion is new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'book','title' %></p>
<p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
<%= text_field 'book','price'%></p>
<p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
<%= text_field 'subject','subject'%></p>
<p><label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
<%= text_area 'book','description'%></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create"%>
<%= link_to 'Back',{:action=>'list'}%>
```

routers.rb is

```
Library::Application.routes.draw do
  get "book/list"

  get "book/show"

  get "book/new"

  get "book/create"

  get "book/edit"

  get "book/update"

  get "book/delete"

    resources :books, :only => [:new, :create]
    match '/books' => 'books#create', :via => :post
```

Here is the html code for new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/book/create" method="post">
<p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
<input id="book_title" name="book[title]" size="30" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
<input id="book_price" name="book[price]" size="30" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:
<input id="subject_subject" name="subject[subject]" size="30" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
<textarea cols="40" id="book_description" name="book[description]" rows="20">
</textarea></p>
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create" />
<a href="/book/list">Back</a>
```

Here is the bookcontoller.rb

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
   def list
      @books = Book.find(:all)
   end
   def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   end
   def new
      @book = Book.new
      @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
   end
   def create
      @book = Book.new(params[:book])
      if @book.save
            redirect_to :action => 'list'
      else
            @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
            render :action => 'new'
      end
   end
   def edit
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
   end
   def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
         redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
      else
         @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
         render :action => 'edit'
      end
   end
   def delete
      Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
      redirect_to :action => 'list'
   end
   def show_subjects
      @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
   end
end
```

Comment: and what you have in controller ? def create .....end ?? is it thr?

Comment: controller code is included

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just include   `post "book/create"` in your router.rb file

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see from your question you are fighting against Rails convention which makes everything harder. You should:

- Only have `resources :books` in routes.rb
- Use the form helper `form_for(@book)` which will generate the correct form to create a book in new.erb.

I recommend a good read of the Rails guides.The following guides are especially relevant to your question and how to fix your problems:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your routes.rb file to just include this:

```
Library::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :books, :except => [:index] do
    collection do
      get :list
      get :show_subjects
    end
  end
end
```